# What is the functor in this example?

Tags: haskell, functor

I have the following line of code:

```
fmap (*2) (*11) 3
```

I'm trying to understand what my functor is in this example, because when I check the type I get this:

```
Prelude> :t fmap (*2) (*11) 3
fmap (*2) (*11) 3 :: Num b => b
```

and I don't see anything resembling a functor in there. If I do a partial application (is that what removing the 3 is called?) I get the following:

```
Prelude> :t fmap (*2) (*11)
fmap (*2) (*11) :: Num a => a -> a
```

and I still don't see anything that looks like a functor in there.

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The functor in question is the function functor.  The function functor is defined as

```
instance Functor ((->) a) where
    fmap f g = f . g
```

Where `(->) a b ~ a -> b`, just making the `->` operator into the infix form.  So this code reduces to

```
(*2) . (*11) $ 3
```

Comment: Awesome, I didn't realise that a function is also a functor!